# Parse custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uitableview

I am trying to make a custom tableview cell for an iPad app, using the Parse framework. When i query without the custom cell, it works fine, but as soon as i am changing the cell identifier, i am just stuck at the loading icon.

The code goes as follows:

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"specielCelle";

 sagerCelle *cell = (sagerCelle *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[sagerCelle alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

 // Configure the cell
     cell.lblPolice.text = [object objectForKey:@"police"];
 //cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
 //cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:self.imageKey];

 return cell;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean stuck at the loading dialog? Does it crash? Have you debugged where it is getting stuck?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you registering your custom class with the UITableView on startup?

Comment: I have imported my custom cell class .h file, and named the cell identifier, associated the .h file with the custom cell, and all i get is a spinning loading icon, nothing shows up. If i comment out the "custom part", the query is loaded, but no custom layout.

Answer (score -1):

Here my advices,(By the way the question is not clear)

Firstly change your identifier with an indexpath.Row

```
    NSString *cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CELL_%d",(int)indexPath.row];
```

Second

if you are changing your existing cell then you are not be able to go inside of the block of

```
if(cell==nil)
```

because your cell is not nil. Write else condition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Change your identifier with an indexPath.row"?!? Do not ever do that. This is truly dreadful advice. It completely defeats cell recycling.

Comment: What's wrong with using identifier with cell number? I always use this way

Comment: It is a very bad idea. It completely defeats cell reuse, and forces the system to create a unique cell for every row in your table view, which will cause you to chew through memory needlessly.